# python string convert to datetime doesn't work

Tags: python, datetime, replace, type-conversion, python-datetime

I'm trying to convert a string, I got from my program, to `datetime.dateime` but it doesn't seem to work because I have the wrong format? The thing is, I have the right format...
Here is some code:

```
from datetime import datetime
Timer = "27.10.2022 • 08:24:03"
Timer = Timer.replace(".", "/")
Timer = Timer.replace("•", "", 1)
Timer = Timer.replace(" ", "", 1)
print(Timer)
NewT = datetime.strptime(Timer, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")
print(NewT)
print(type(NewT))
```

Output is:

27/10/2022 08:24:03

> ValueError: time data '27/10/2022 08:24:03' does not match format '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'

I don't see where the Problem is because you can see the formatted string is the exact format.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try with capital Y instead of small y?

Comment: Damn, thanks that worked haha didnt think the solution would be so simple. Why does it make such a differents if the y is not capital?

Comment: voted to close as (pretty common) typo; `%y` for 2-digit years, `%Y` for 4-digit years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does work, you have to use `%Y` instead of `%y`

`%Y` works with years like 2022, 2023

`%y` works with years like 22, 23